# Datagridmapper Symfony Custom Callback With Join Entity

Tags: sonata-admin

I am using sonata admin as a back-end for my project.

I am trying to filter records, which have NULL value in database and whose column is from another entity.

Have two entities: One is Medical second one is User.

In **Medical** I am trying to put a search filter for 'isLanguagePurchase', which is in **User** entity.

Code :

```
$datagridMapper->add('user.isLanguagePurchase', '', array('label' => 'Is Language Purchase','callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if ($value['value'] == '1') {
                    $queryBuilder->andWhere($alias . '.isLanguagePurchase = 1');
                }
                if ($value['value'] == '0') {
                    $queryBuilder->andWhere($alias . '.isLanguagePurchase IS NULL');
                    $queryBuilder->orWhere($alias . '.isLanguagePurchase = 0');
                }
            },'field_type' => 'choice','field_options' => array('choices'=> array('Yes' => 1, 'No' => 0))));
```

However, it is only searching 0 and 1 value records, not for NULL value records.